# Uploading a File (Multipart/Form data) to Server Failed in Android using ion library

Tags: java, c#, android, android-ion

I am new in android ,and  am trying to upload a file to server using ion library 
[ion library](https://github.com/koush/ion#post-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-and-read-a-string) but the file crashes. with this error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-55725
                                                                                           Process: transitions.com.example.huzy_kamz.interview, PID: 4635
                                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:209)
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:123)
                                                                                               at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:122)
                                                                                               at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:200)
                                                                                               at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:196)
                                                                                               at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:141)
                                                                                               at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
                                                                                               at transitions.com.example.huzy_kamz.interview.MainActivity.uploadFile(MainActivity.java:131)
                                                                                               at transitions.com.example.huzy_kamz.interview.MainActivity$2$1.run(MainActivity.java:66)
                                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is how am using ion library to upload my file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PICK_FILE_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String selectedFilePath;
    private String SERVER_URL = "http://192.168.43.104:8093/PoliceApp/FileUpload.aspx";
    ImageView ivAttachment;
    private String UPLOAD_URL ="http://192.168.43.104:8093/PoliceApp/ImageUpload.aspx";
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private EditText firstname_edt,lastname_edt,email_edt,jobtitle_edt,source_edt;
    private TextView directory_txt;
    private Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        firstname_edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstname_edt);
        lastname_edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastname_edt);
        email_edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email_edt);
        jobtitle_edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jobtitle_edt);
        source_edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.source_edt);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        directory_txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.directory_txt);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showFileChooser();
            }
        });

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(selectedFilePath != null){
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"","Uploading File...",true);

                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //creating new thread to handle Http Operations


                            uploadFile(selectedFilePath);
                          //  OnSendFileInfo();

                        }
                    }).start();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please choose a File First",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });






    }


    // Gallery pick

    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        //sets the select file to all types of files
        intent.setType("*/*");
        //allows to select data and return it
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        //starts new activity to select file and return data
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose File to Upload.."),PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST){
                if(data == null){
                    //no data present
                    return;
                }


                Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
                selectedFilePath = FilePath.getPath(this,selectedFileUri);
                Log.i(TAG,"Selected File Path:" + selectedFilePath);

                if(selectedFilePath != null && !selectedFilePath.equals("")){
                    directory_txt.setText(selectedFilePath);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Cannot upload file to server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }





    public void uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath){




        final  ProgressDialog pd;
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Uploading File...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
        final String url_ = "";

        Ion.with(MainActivity.this)
                .load(SERVER_URL)
                .uploadProgressDialog(pd)
                .setMultipartParameter("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath)
                .setMultipartFile("archive", "application/zip", new File(selectedFilePath))
                .asString()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {




                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," "+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        pd.dismiss();



                    }
                });


    }
}
```

**My Method Contain ion library to Upload a PDF file .**

```
 public void uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath){




        final  ProgressDialog pd;
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Uploading ...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
        final String url_ = "";
        //File file = new File(this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/thesubdirectory/the.zip");
        File f = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+selectedFilePath);


        try {
            RandomAccessFile rf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw");
            rf.setLength(1024 * 1024 * 2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        File echoedFile = getFileStreamPath("echo");
            Ion.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load(SERVER_URL)
                    .uploadProgressDialog(pd)
                    .setMultipartFile("uploaded_file",f)
                    .write(echoedFile)
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<File>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, File result) {


                            try {

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                System.out.println("Error  " + result);

                                pd.dismiss();

                            } catch (Exception e1) {
                                System.out.println("Error  " + e1);
                            }
                            pd.dismiss();


                        }
                    });



    }
```

I don't where am wrong please i need your help, where am i wrong.
My back end is working fine , but the problem is in the uploading process.

This is my C# Api to locate the File in a specified folder.

```
 public void FileSave(HttpPostedFile file)
    {

        try
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/FileStorage"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }

            Response.Write("Upload successfull");

        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Write("An Error Ocurred");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Check your "selectedFilePath" for existence . i.e if file exists or not . Ion will throw exception if file doesn't exists

Comment: You try to show a dialog in a background thread; `uploadFile` called from a Thread. Have a look at AsyncTask: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: yes i checked it in the TextView @ADM ,and it shows the path , but may be i mess up somewhere in ion code please check it for me well , it's a bit tricky thanks

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE, yes it does shows a dialog , after some minutes it crashes and brings that error.

Comment: @ADM, seems you know the ion structure , please help me achieve this

Comment: Your markup for the backtrace is completely wrong, and you rejected my edit that corrected this... Please fix it.

Comment: no problem you can edit it , but its better also to help me out am still stuck

Comment: @jhildstack can you share your exception details ?

Comment: The first code above is my exception @ÅdəəlÅhmåd

Comment: reply the comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i  have found out a simple way of uploading or  posting  **multipart/form-data**  with an upload progress bar. may be this could help.

*Suppose you  server is waiting for the following data :*

1.**File**(PDF,Image,Audio,Video etc.).

2.**Name**

3.**Email**

4.**Address.**

and you want to upload that information once in a URL be it an **Absolute URL** or a **Relative URL**, ion library is easy , precise, efficient and much better in this.

**STEP 1:**

declare your `URI`

```
private Uri filePath;
```

**STEP 2:**

then Pick the file from your gallery , here it's your choice you identify any kind of files you want a user to view, me here i have identified a PDF file.
on this line `intent.setType("application/pdf");`

```
private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Pdf"), PICK_PDF_REQUEST);
    }

    //handling the image chooser activity result
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_PDF_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + filePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

then you can call `showFileChooser()` in the `Button` for a click to access your gallery.

**STEP 3:**

a) Make a method   `Upload()` containing ion library to start the job.  If you see in this method , i first declared the `file,name, email,address` , for `file` it gets the **URI** data of a selected file or the path file , then `name, email,address`, it gets the data from EditText , you have to declare EditText to get the data.

b) Then identify the **URL** you want to use in `Posting` mine is `url_`. but make sure you include `POST`, in the **load** section `.load("POST",url_)`.
c) Then you set the file by using `.setMultipartFile("File", file)` and the rest of the parameters by setting **MultipartParameter** `.setMultipartParameter("Name", name)` and so on.

```
public void Upload() {

        String file= FilePath.getPath(this, filePath);
        final String name = name_edt.getText().toString();
        final String email = email_edt.getText().toString();
        final String address = address_edt.getText().toString();
        

        final ProgressDialog pd;
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Logging in...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
        final String url_ = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        final File file = new File(Uri.parse(path).toString());



        Ion.with(MainActivity.this)
                .load("POST",url_)
                .progressDialog(pd)
                .setMultipartFile("file", file)
                .setMultipartParameter("Name", name)
                .setMultipartParameter("Email", email)
                .setMultipartParameter("Address.", address)
               
                .asString()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {


                        //     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+file,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        System.out.println("Error " + e);
                       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception : " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        pd.dismiss();


                    }
                });
    }
```

Then you are good to go , according to your C# API , the file will be able to save in the Folder. Even others use `Php` or any other language you can create your own Api to save a file in your server folder

**Hope it works well.**

Answer (score 1):

Remove Thread from calling chain as Ion manages that for you and your exception is not related to Ion FYI.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(selectedFilePath != null){
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"","Uploading File...",true);
                        uploadFile(selectedFilePath);
                      //  OnSendFileInfo();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please choose a File First",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

You can not use a View in Non Ui thread . So as i am seeing that you are creating a progress dialog inside your upload method which is being called for a thread .That code should be in Main thread only.

Comment: thanks for the answer , it nolonger crashes , but i toasted , now it shows null , is it because of my ion structure , it seems it doesnt see the file path , it is visible in the textview why is that

Comment: that you have to check from [here](https://github.com/koush/ion). Why are you using application/zip in multipart params . While you are uploading a image file . read the documentation first

Comment: what am i supposed to use , suppose i want to choose a pdf file

Comment: Please help me on that @ADM

Comment: Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312230/proper-mime-media-type-for-pdf-files) for content type .

Comment: so according to what i saw the MIME for pdf is `application/pdf`

Comment: man it seems it shows null , i have tried to update my code but it says null

Comment: is the null you are talking about , URI of file ?